# How to return every 5 items from a list in python?

Tags: python, list

I am using python and would like to return every 5 items from a list and put them into csv format.

Also, if there are less than 5 items in the iteration then I need to zero fill to get 5 items.

I am using a fairly old version of python 2.1 which can not be changed so i do not have access to 'iter'.

Thanks.

Comment: Uh, must admit I've forgotten what was possible those days...

Comment: @user: Is there any reason you are still using 2.1? It was released on April 17, 2001.

Comment: Yeah, using an old version of zope. We are moving to a new version and a new framework but the old version still needs updates :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Including the padding, this might work.  (There are list comprehensions in 2.1, right? Just looked it up -- they were added in 2.0.)

```
a = the_list
a += [0] * (-len(a) % 5)
result = [a[i:i + 5] for i in range(0, len(a), 5)]
```

In less ancient Python, I would replace the last line by

```
result = zip(*[iter(a)] * 5)
```

Comment: Mutates input list. Wastes memory on list of rows. Doesn't address CSV requirement.

Comment: FWIW, `(4 - (len(a) - 1) % 5)` reduces to `(-len(a) % 5`

Comment: @John: I'm used to the C semantics of `%`, but for Python this simplification is indeed possible.

Comment: Thanks for the code, in the end I used this one. I created a little for loop and used a string.join to get it into a csv format. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you want?

```
rows = []
while a_list:
    rows.append(a_list[:5])
    a_list = a_list[5:]
```

Comment: I was going to suggest a one-liner: items = [l[i:i+5] for i in range(0, len(l), 5)]. But the above should work too. I wonder if the question author expects a complete solution with all specific features, though (it sounds like a homework question).

Comment: @vartec: I am not sure, I don't have a Python 2.1 install here, to test it.

Comment: Worst homework assignment ever: "don't use any language features added in the last 10 years."

Comment: @ehabkost -- hmm, actually seems it's there since 2.0 :-)

Comment: I believe generators were added in 2.2. Otherwise I would have gone that route.

Comment: nah not homework question. The issue is that I have to use an old module that someone created so we can build a pdf. The problem is that it only takes a csv string of 5 items at a time (to build a table).

Comment: @nmichaels: Doesn't zero-fill the last row. The try/except is redundant; the tried statement will NEVER raise IndexError.

Answer (score 0):

this works in python 2.4.  Not sure if everything is possible in 2.1:

```
def to_csv(l, columns=5):
  l = l + [0]*((columns-1) - (len(l)-1)%columns)
  ll = [ l[i:len(l):columns] for i in range(columns) ]
  for row in zip(*ll): print ', '.join( str(xi) for xi in row )
```

Comment: This will pad `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` by 4 zeros, and it won't pad `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` at all.

Comment: All the defects exhibited by some other answers, plus introduces a space after the comma -- less likely to be handled sensibly by a CSV reader than no-extra-space e.g. 'skipinitialspace' is not the default for Python's csv.reader

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
# 1. Doesn't mutate the input list
# 2. Doesn't waste memory on a temporary list of rows
# 3. Handles the CSV requirement, including quoting strings properly

float_type = type(0.0)

def csv_escape(pyrow, quotechar='"', delimiter=',', terminator='\r\n'):
    outlist = []
    for obj in pyrow:
        if isinstance(obj, float_type):
            s = repr(obj) # Get full precision. BTW the csv module doesn't do this :-(
        else:
            s = str(obj) # This may need further elaboration
        if quotechar in s:
            x = quotechar + s.replace(quotechar, quotechar+quotechar) + quotechar
        elif delimiter in s or '\r' in s or '\n' in s:
            x = quotechar + s + quotechar
        else:
            x = s
        outlist.append(x)
    return delimiter.join(outlist) + terminator

def emit_list_in_slices(alist, file_handle,
                        slice_size=5, pad_value=0, slice_formatter=csv_escape):
    for i in xrange(0, len(alist), slice_size):
        row = alist[i:i+slice_size]
        n = len(row)
        if n and n != slice_size:
            row.extend([pad_value] * (slice_size - n))
        file_handle.write(csv_escape(row))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_list = range(9) + [1.0 / 11.0, 'He said "Hello"', 'foo,bar', 'zot']
    f = open('demo.csv', 'wb') #### Note: binary
    emit_list_in_slices(test_list, f)
    f.close()
```

Running with this Python: Python 2.1.3 (#35, Apr  8 2002, 17:47:50) [MSC 32 bit (Intel)] on win32:

```
C:\junk>\python21\python csvslice21.py

C:\junk>more demo.csv
0,1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8,0.090909090909090912
"He said ""Hello""","foo,bar",zot,0,0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work in Python 2.1 (I don't have it installed here to test).  We leave the input array unmodified.

```
# create input
a = list(range(20, 43))

values = [a[i:i+5] for i in range(0, len(a), 5)]
values[-1] += (-len(values[-1]) % 5) * [0]
csv = [','.join([str(v) for v in vs]) for vs in values]
```